# Unable to receive $_POST data when using directories

Tags: php, post, directory

I have a problem regarding a Log In page in my application, I'm doing everything -I suppose- I used to do regarding forms, but unable to receive data in my server php page, please help

Client side code :

```
<form method="post" action="../control/authentication.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">LogIn</button>
  <label for="signupButton">Don't have an account? Sign up here</label>
  <button name="signup" id="signupButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info">SignUp</button>
</form>
```

Server side code :

```
include_once('../config.php');
require_once(ROOT . 'Connexion.php');
$connect = new Connexion();

if(isset($_POST["inputEmail"]) && isset($_POST["inputPassword"])){
    $email=$_POST["inputEmail"];
    $pass=$_POST["inputPassword"];

    $st = $connect->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client WHERE email='" . $email . "' AND password='" . $pass ."'")->fetch();
    if ($st['COUNT(*)'] == 1)
        header('Location: index.php');
}
else{
    echo 'I didn\'t receive anything!';
}
```

I'm getting each time the echo message (I didn't receive anything!)
Am I missing anything ? Please help !

Comment: there is no `$_POST["submit"]` in your form buttons dont submit you want the submit input

Comment: What do you get if you put `print_r($_POST);` before your `if isset` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Put `if(isset($_POST["inputEmail"]) && isset($_POST["inputPassword"]))` instead `isset($_POST["submit"])`.

Comment: Here I reupdated my code, still getting the same thing!

Answer (score 0):

You can check just `isset($_POST)` then get each value, since there is no `$_POST['submit']`.

Comment: When using $_POST I get indefined index for inputEmail and inputPassword, where could be the bug, I think it's something related to HTTP protocol or the port I'm using, I'm on phpStorm on port 63342

Comment: That means your got $_POST but no elements? Could you show `print_r($_POST)` or `print_r($_REQUEST)`?